# Бумажная полоска на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Задана полоска длиной 2^k клеток и шириной в одну клетку. Полоску сгибают пополам так, чтобы правая половинка оказалась под левой. Сгибание продолжают до тех пор, пока сверху находится больше одной клетки. Необходимо пронумеровать клетки таким образом, чтобы после окончания сгибания полосы номера клеток в получившейся колонке были расположены в порядке 1,2,3,4,...,2^k.

Я написал код к ней

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaApp extends JFrame
{
    public JavaApp(){
        setTitle("Полоска");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        add(new Panel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JavaApp jApp = new JavaApp();
    }
}


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Console;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    static JTextField jText = new JTextField(15);
    JButton button = new JButton("Расчитать");
    static JTextField jRes = new JTextField();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Введите k:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Результат:");

    public Panel()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        createInterface();
    }

    private void createInterface()
    {
        jText.setBounds(40,40,100,30);
        setVisible(true);
        add(jText);
        button.setBounds(150,40,100,30);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
        jRes.setBounds(40,100,300,30);
        add(jRes);
        label1.setBounds(40,20,100,20);
        label2.setBounds(40,75,100,20);
        add(label1);
        add(label2);
    }

    static int[] getMass(int count)
    {
        int[] mass = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = i++;
        }
        return mass;
    }

    static void change(int width, int height, int Xl, int Yl, int Xr, int Yr,  int[][] aMatrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                aMatrix[Xr + j][Yr + i] = aMatrix[Xl - j][Yl + (width - i) - 1];
                //System.out.println(aMatrix[Xl - j][Yl + (width - i) - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    static void calc()
    {
        double k = Double.parseDouble(jText.getText());
        //System.out.println(jText.getText());
        int count = (int) Math.pow(2,k);

        int width = 1, Heigh = count / 2, XL = count, YL = 0, XR = 0, YR = 1;

        int[] myMass = getMass(count);

        int[][] matrix = new int[myMass.length][myMass.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myMass.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myMass.length; j++) 
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < myMass.length; i++) 
        {
            matrix[i][0] = myMass[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            change(width * (int)Math.pow(2,i), Heigh / (int)Math.pow(2,i), XL / (int)Math.pow(2,i) - 1, YL, XR, YR * (int)Math.pow(2,i), matrix);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //jRes.setText(String.valueOf(matrix[0][i]));
            System.out.println(matrix[0][i]);
            if(i != count - 1)
            {
                jRes.setText(" ");
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calc();
    }
}
```

Почему он не выдает нужный результат?

Comment: Я полагаю, в приведённом коде правая половина массива отражается вниз k раз. Отладка покажет, где сбои. Уберите только эти дурацкие `pow(2,i)`, вещественная арифметика тут не к месту (`1<<i`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class JavaApp1 {

    static int[] GetMass(int count)
    {

        int[] mass = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return mass;
    }

    static void Change(int width, int height, int Xl, int Yl, int Xr, int Yr, int[][] aMatrix) throws IOException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                aMatrix[Xr + j][ Yr + i] = aMatrix[Xl - j] [Yl + (width - i) - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader("in.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double k = 0;
        try {
            k = Double.parseDouble(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("in.txt")).get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int count = (int)Math.pow(2, k);

        int Width = 1, Height = count / 2, XL = count, YL = 0, XR = 0, YR = 1;

        int[] myMass = GetMass(count);

        int[][] matrix = new int[myMass.length][myMass.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < myMass.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myMass.length; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < myMass.length; i++)
        {
            matrix[i][0] = myMass[i];
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            try {
                Change(Width * (int)Math.pow(2, i), Height / (int)Math.pow(2, i), XL / (int)Math.pow(2, i) - 1, YL, XR, YR * (int)Math.pow(2, i),  matrix);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            System.out.println(matrix[0][i]);
            try {
                writer.write(matrix[0][i]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (i != count - 1) {
                try {
                    writer.write(" ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот на Python тот же подход c разворотом прямоугольных частей размером `w x h`  [работает](https://ideone.com/VMUGop) (ср. http://oeis.org/A281589), так что Вы, наверное, что-то с индексами напутали или использование `pow` не к тому результату привело.

```
k = 4
n = 1 << k
A = [[(i+1) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
w = n // 2
h = 1
for i in range(k):
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            A[2*h -1- y][w - 1 - x] = A[y][w + x]
    w //= 2
    h *= 2

for m in range(n):
    print(A[m][0], end = " ")

>>> 1 16 9 8 5 12 13 4 3 14 11 6 7 10 15 2
```